# replace value into select field into the admin panel

Tags: ruby, padrino

I created two models:

Answers
AnswersTypes `{id, text}`

The latter one could accept two values `{correct / wrong}` as text.

I modified the admin panel to accept an html select field to link an AnswerType directly within the Answer.

Now the issue is that in the Answer's list page I have a column AnswerType in which i could see the ID of the linked AnswerType but I would like to see the text instead of the ID.

In the file `/admin/answers/views/index.erb` the field is:

`<td><%= answer.answer_type %=></td>`

How could I modify it to select the text starting from that id !?

Thank you very much and ... I have to say that Padrino Rocks!

**EDIT: adding some infos**
`SCHEMA`
    create_table "answer_types"
        t.string "text"
    [..]

```
create_table "answers"
    t.string "text"
    t.integer "answer_type_id"
[..]
```

`models/answer.rb`
    class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
        [..]
        has_one :answerType

`models/answer_types.rb`

class AnswerTypes < ActiveRecord::Base
[..]
belongs_to :answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the `text` value from an `AnswerType` object by calling `text` on the object:

```
<td><%= answer.answer_type.text %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I tried it but it doesn't work.

In my table I have:
answer_types (ID | text)
               1 | right
               2 | wrong

answer (ID | text | answer_id)
         1 | foo  | 1

Right now, when i click on the Answer's List Padrino retrieves:
foo | 1

Instead of that result I would like to receive "foo | right".

If I apply your code, Padrino says:
NoMethodError at /admin/answers
undefined method 'text' for 2:Fixnum

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, does it give you an error? What do you see if you put `<%= answer.answer_type.inspect %>`?

Comment: Sorry Charles,
I modified my own answer :)

With the inspect, I receive the correct ID. Like If I use just answer.answer_type.

Comment: It seems like the association may not be set up appropriately. One thing I noticed is that in your `Answer` model, your column should be named `answer_type_id`. Did you set up `:has_one` and `:belongs_to` associations in your `Answer` and `AnswerType` models?

Comment: Hi Charles, I added some infos in a separate answer!

Answer (score 0):

I try to give you some more informations:

In *db/schema.rb* I have:

```
create_table "answer_types", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "text"
end

create_table "answers", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "text"
  t.integer "answer_type_id"
end
```

In *models/answer.rb* I have:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :text
    belongs_to :question
    has_one :answer_type
end
```

In *models/answer_types.rb* I have:
    class AnswerTypes < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :answer
    end

So in *admin/views/answers/index.erb* I have:

```
<td><%= answer.answer_type_id %></td>
```

Which prints correctly the **answer_type_id** linked to the answer.

Coming back on the initial question: how could I replace the **answer_type_id** printing the answer_types text field?

Thanks!

Comment: I found out the problem! It was really silly!!

Simply within the **answer** model I named the *belongs_to* association *:answerType* instead of **answer_type** !!

Right now I could access the answer_type title just typing **answer.answer_type.title**!

Thanks to Charles for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!